# I need to remove an empty array with PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

This my first post but have used this forum for years for some great advice so thank you to everyone that contributes. I have trawled this site and it feels like all of Google but still can't find a solution to my problem.

I have a task at work to supply a third party with some data in JSON format, this is taken from MS SQL Server and saved as a csv. I then use PowerShell to format it the way they want it in JSON.

After days of work its all working as it should apart from one bit, I need to remove empty arrays that will happen in my data if a customer doesn't have a device. Here is my PowerShell script;

```
$jsonBase = @{}
$requestor = 'exportedData'
$filename = (get-date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
$csvData   = Import-Csv -Path example.csv

Function Remove-Null {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        # Object from which to remove the null values.
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline,Mandatory)]
        $InputObject,
        # Instead of also removing values that are empty strings, include them
        # in the output.
        [Switch]$LeaveEmptyStrings,
        # Additional entries to remove, which are either present in the
        # properties list as an object or as a string representation of the
        # object.
        # I.e. $item.ToString().
        [Object[]]$AlsoRemove = @()
    )
    Process {
        # Iterate InputObject in case input was passed as an array
        ForEach ($obj in $InputObject) {
            $obj | Select-Object -Property (
                $obj.PSObject.Properties.Name | Where-Object {
                    -not (
                        # If prop is null, remove it
                        $null -eq $obj.$_ -or
                        # If -LeaveEmptyStrings is not specified and the property
                        # is an empty string, remove it
                        (-not $LeaveEmptyStrings.IsPresent -and
                            [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($obj.$_)) -or
                        # If AlsoRemove contains the property, remove it
                        $AlsoRemove.Contains($obj.$_) -or
                        # If AlsoRemove contains the string representation of
                        # the property, remove it
                        $AlsoRemove.Contains($obj.$_.ToString()) -OR
                        # remove if it contains a string of 'NULL'
                        'NULL' -eq $obj.$_

                    )
                }
            )
        }
    }
}


# get an array of PSObjects
# we use 'Group-Object customerID' here to allow extra orders and PIDs
$allcustomers = $csvData | Group-Object customerID | ForEach-Object {
    $orders = $_.Group | Select-Object -Unique orderType,orderStart,orderEnd,supplier
    $devices = $_.Group | Select-Object -Unique deviceID,@{Name='deviceName';Expression={$_.customerID}},allocationStart,allocationEnd | Where-Object {$_.deviceID -ne 'NULL'}
    $customer = $_.Group[0] | Select-Object -Unique * -ExcludeProperty orderType,orderStart,orderEnd,supplier,deviceID,allocationStart,allocationEnd

    $newdevices = $devices | Remove-Null

    $customer | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'orders' -Value @($orders)
    $customer | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'devices' -Value @($newdevices)

    # output the customer object
$customer
}

# gathered above into a new object and convert that to JSON

$json1 = [PsCustomObject]@{
    applicationID = "1"
    customers = @($allcustomers)
}

$jsonBase.Add("exportedData",$json1)

$jsonBase | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5 | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 -Path "${filename}.json"
```

```
{
    "exportedData":  {
                         "applicationID":  "1",
                         "customers":  [
                                           {
                                               "customerID":  "1339306",
                                               "customerName":  "Fake Customer 1",
                                               "customerDateOfBirth":  "19870525",
                                               "customerAddressText":  "Fake Address 1",
                                               "Manager":  "Manager 1",
                                               "xID":  "UCYWIU",
                                               "xRef":  "AHZVXP",
                                               "orders":  [
                                                              {
                                                                  "orderType":  "Online",
                                                                  "orderStart":  "20210411230000",
                                                                  "orderEnd":  "20220410230000",
                                                                  "supplier":  "Supplier A"
                                                              }
                                                          ],
                                               "devices":  [
                                                               {
                                                                   "deviceID":  "637148",
                                                                   "deviceName":  "1339306",
                                                                   "allocationStart":  "20210412192100"
                                                               }
                                                           ]
                                           },
                                           {
                                               "customerID":  "1339321",
                                               "customerName":  "Fake Customer 2",
                                               "customerDateOfBirth":  "19960102",
                                               "customerAddressText":  "Fake Address 2",
                                               "Manager":  "Manager 2",
                                               "xID":  "ULYKHN",
                                               "xRef":  "STKRFZ",
                                               "orders":  [
                                                              {
                                                                  "orderType":  "Online",
                                                                  "orderStart":  "20210413230000",
                                                                  "orderEnd":  "20210720230000",
                                                                  "supplier":  "Supplier B"
                                                              }
                                                          ],
                                               "devices":  [
                                                               {
                                                                   "deviceID":  "641358",
                                                                   "deviceName":  "1339321",
                                                                   "allocationStart":  "20210417183200",
                                                                   "allocationEnd":  "20210508181500"
                                                               },
                                                               {
                                                                   "deviceID":  "641358",
                                                                   "deviceName":  "1339321",
                                                                   "allocationStart":  "20210508181500",
                                                                   "allocationEnd":  "20210612190500"
                                                               },
                                                               {
                                                                   "deviceID":  "641358",
                                                                   "deviceName":  "1339321",
                                                                   "allocationStart":  "20210612190500",
                                                                   "allocationEnd":  "20210721193400"
                                                               }
                                                           ]
                                           },
                                           {
                                               "customerID":  "1339325",
                                               "customerName":  "Fake Customer 3",
                                               "customerDateOfBirth":  "19750405",
                                               "customerAddressText":  "Fake Address 3",
                                               "Manager":  "Manager 3",
                                               "xID":  "BCQPQJ",
                                               "xRef":  "MTTJBJ",
                                               "orders":  [
                                                              {
                                                                  "orderType":  "Email",
                                                                  "orderStart":  "20210418230000",
                                                                  "orderEnd":  "20220418230000",
                                                                  "supplier":  "Supplier C"
                                                              }
                                                          ],
                                               "devices":  [
                                                               {
                                                                   "deviceID":  "641360",
                                                                   "deviceName":  "1339325",
                                                                   "allocationStart":  "20210419205600",
                                                                   "allocationEnd":  "20210602211100"
                                                               },
                                                               {
                                                                   "deviceID":  "646142",
                                                                   "deviceName":  "1339325",
                                                                   "allocationStart":  "20210602211100",
                                                                   "allocationEnd":  "20210628194500"
                                                               },
                                                               {
                                                                   "deviceID":  "641831",
                                                                   "deviceName":  "1339325",
                                                                   "allocationStart":  "20210628194600"
                                                               }
                                                           ]
                                           },
                                           {
                                               "customerID":  "1355689",
                                               "customerName":  "Fake Customer 4",
                                               "customerDateOfBirth":  "19891005",
                                               "customerAddressText":  "Fake Address 4",
                                               "Manager":  "Manager 4",
                                               "xID":  "OYNLQL",
                                               "xRef":  "DMSUAP",
                                               "orders":  [
                                                              {
                                                                  "orderType":  "Email",
                                                                  "orderStart":  "20210728230000",
                                                                  "orderEnd":  "20220728230000",
                                                                  "supplier":  "Supplier B"
                                                              }
                                                          ],
                                               "devices":  [

                                                           ]
                                           },
                                           {
                                               "customerID":  "1355826",
                                               "customerName":  "Fake Customer 5",
                                               "customerDateOfBirth":  "19891218",
                                               "customerAddressText":  "Fake Address 5",
                                               "Manager":  "Manager 5",
                                               "xID":  "XSWTNH",
                                               "xRef":  "FCIIYO",
                                               "orders":  [
                                                              {
                                                                  "orderType":  "Online",
                                                                  "orderStart":  "20210728230000",
                                                                  "orderEnd":  "20220728230000",
                                                                  "supplier":  "Supplier B"
                                                              }
                                                          ],
                                               "devices":  [

                                                           ]
                                           }
                                       ]
                     }
}
```

What I want to do is remove any empty arrays, so the ones that don't have devices I want to hide/remove the array completely so that the "devices" : [] doesn't appear.

I have used a function to remove elements from an array if the value is a string 'NULL'.

I have looked at ForEach and ForEach-Object but cant seem to iterate over the arrays themselves to remove them. As a last attempt I was going to read the JSON back in and use -replace to change the string but couldnt get it to work with the carriage returns and spaces.

This is what the CSV looks like.

[The CSV that is imported and transformed in PowerShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unG5j.png)

If anyone could help that would be so great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires an [recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).
To make things easier, I recommend to use the [`ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json#parameters) parameter. This way, you only need to deal with arrays and hashtables:

$Data = $Json |ConvertFrom-Json

```
function Remove-EmptyArrays ($Object) {
    if ($Object -is [Array]) {
        foreach ($Item in $Object) { Remove-EmptyArrays $Item }
    }
    elseif ($Object -is [HashTable]) {
        foreach ($Key in @($Object.get_Keys())) {
            if ($Object[$Key] -is [Array] -and $Object[$Key].get_Count() -eq 0) {
                $Object.Remove($Key)
            }
            else { Remove-EmptyArrays $Object[$Key] }
        }
    }
    elseif ($Object -is [PSCustomObject]) {
        foreach ($Name in @($Object.psobject.properties.Name)) {
            if ($Object.$Name -is [Array] -and $Object.$Name.get_Count() -eq 0) {
                $Object.PSObject.Properties.Remove($Name)
            }
            else { Remove-EmptyArrays $Object.$Name }
        }
    }
}

Remove-EmptyArrays $Data

$Data |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9
```

---

**Update 2021-07-30**
I have updated the script to also support [`[PSCustomObject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject) types to support Windows PowerShell where `ConvertFrom-Json` doesn't have a `-AsHashTable` parameter.

Comment: Hello iRon, thank you so much for getting back to me on this problem. It's really annoying but I only have PSVersion 5.1.1 at work and restricted and unable to download a later version where this -AsHashTable would work. Is there any way around this? thanks again :)

Comment: You're a PowerShell genius, thank you so much it works perfectly. I really appreciate the help.